# SQL CTE how can this query run faster than 20 minutes?

Tags: sql, common-table-expression

I hope I can get some assistance as I am still rather new in SQL programming.

The following code works but takes approx. 21 minutes to run. Can this query be executed faster with the same result?

Table EOD has approximately 46 million records and six columns (datatypes follow names):

```
Symbol varchar(15)      
Date Date   
Open Float  
High Float  
Low Float   
Close Float  
Volume varchar(15)
```

The symbol will vary depending on my analysis and thus did not write a where clause in the CTE "SMA".

Thanks and let me know if I can be more clear.  Wised.

```
with SMA as 
(
    select
        *,
        -- column names: symbol, open, low, high, close, volume(varchar(15))
        ((lag ([close],10)over (order by symbol, date)              --#varSMANUM must also change number for field 'WM'!
            +lag ([close],9)over (order by symbol, date) 
            +lag ([close],8)over (order by symbol, date) 
            +lag ([close],7)over (order by symbol, date) 
            +lag ([close],6)over (order by symbol, date) 
            +lag ([close],5)over (order by symbol, date) 
            +lag ([close],4)over (order by symbol, date) 
            +lag ([close],3)over (order by symbol, date) 
            +lag ([close],2)over (order by symbol, date) 
            +lag ([close],1)over (order by symbol, date) 
            )/ 10) as test,
    (cast(2 as float)/(10    --#varSMANUM must add lag statements above!!!!
            +1)) as WM
    from 
        qwid.dbo.eod 
)
select  
    date,
    [close],
    test 
from 
    SMA 
where 
    symbol = 'aapl' 
order by 
    date;
```

Comment: You have to create some indexes. For example add an index on "date" and include "symbol".

Comment: Please tag the database engine you’re using, include the index definitions, and query plan

Comment: I think you can do `AVG(close) OVER(... PRECDEING 10 ROWS)` to find average of 10 prev rows in one statement.

Answer (score 2):

I think I would start by rewriting the query as:

```
select date, [close],
       avg([close]) over (order by symbol, date rows between 10 preceding and 1 preceding) as test
    test 
from qwid.dbo.eod  
where symbol = 'aapl' 
order by date;
```

Then, I would add an index on `qwid.dbo.eod(symbol, date, [close])`.

Note that this is slightly different than your query for the first few values.  This will return a calculated value when your version would return `NULL`.